# How to hide legend entries from unselected series in altair?

Tags: altair

I have two linked charts with a selection enabled on the left (points) that controls which series are draw on the right (linespoints). I would like to display only the legend entries from the selected points/series.

I was able to partially accomplish this by setting the scale of the color for the series to the selector. When I select points, the legend updates to only show what I selected. However, when no points are selected, all legend entries are present. How can I hide the legend entries when no series are selected?

Example using the cars dataset:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

cars = data.cars()

selector = alt.selection_point(fields=['Origin'], empty=False)

points = alt.Chart(cars).mark_point().encode(
    x='Miles_per_Gallon',
    y='Cylinders',
    color=alt.condition(selector, 'Origin', alt.value('gray')),
    tooltip=['Origin']
).add_params(selector)
linespoints = alt.Chart(cars).mark_line(point=True).encode(
    x='Displacement',
    y='Horsepower',
    color=alt.Color('Origin').scale(domain=selector),
    tooltip='Origin'
).transform_filter(selector)

points | linespoints
```